# IntelliSense doesn't work in Visual Studio Code on Mac

Tags: c#, intellisense, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I am using Visual Studio Code to develop an ASP.NET 5 application on Mac. The issue I am having is that I don't get any [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/csharp) support (e.g. available class methods) beyond simple autocomplete for methods and variables names that I previously typed.

The app targets DNX Core 5.0:

```
"frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

And I have CoreCLR 1.0.0-rc1-update1 installed via DNVM:

> $dnvm list
>
> Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias
>
> ------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----
>
> - 1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin          default

I tried the following to resolve the issue, but with no luck:

- Made sure that a project is selected (fire icon in the bottom right corner)
- Explicitly turned suggestions in `settings.json`

  ```
  {
      "editor.quickSuggestions": true`
  }
  ```

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Get Resharper. Problem solved.

Comment: @Krythic, is there ReShaper for Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, the problem was that, while I had Mono installed on my machine, I didn't have DNX Mono. Installing it via DNVM locally (`dnvm upgrade -r mono`) resolved the issue and now I am having nice IntelliSense support in Visual Studio Code.

Now the long story.

Visual Studio Code uses [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/) to provide IntelliSense support. OmniSharp is a set of tools that provides C# code analysis services through a Nancy-based web API that runs on your machine (great posts on it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OmniSharpMakingCrossplatformNETARealityAndAPleasure.aspx) and [here](http://blog.jonathanchannon.com/2014/11/12/csharp-first-class-citizen-sublime-text/)).

I didn't not get any IntelliSense because OmniSharp ran with errors which I could have easily caught if I paid more attention to Visual Studio Code Output window (`Cmd+L` `L` on Mac). OmniSharp Log (see below) shows that it tried to use `dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1` runtime and then threw an exception because it was not there.

From what I understand, OmniSharp can't use DNX CoreCLR ([because it doesn't support sockets?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/126#issuecomment-158092504)) and needs DNX Mono to run. There is some discussion on this topic in [VS Code GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/126).

Running `dnvm upgrade -r mono` and restarting Visual Studio Code fixed the issue. My DNVM set up now looks like this:
[image]

Please note that you don't have to use DNX Mono for development in order to get IntelliSense to work. You just need to have it installed.

**OmniSharp Log**

> [INFO] Starting OmniSharp at APP_PATH...
>
> [INFO] Started OmniSharp from '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/jrieken.vscode-omnisharp/bin/omnisharp' with process id 34893...
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Omnisharp server running using stdio at location APP_PATH on host 34884.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Scanning APP_PATH for DNX projects
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxPaths] Using runtime '/Users/nsamteladze/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-coreclr-darwin-x64.1.0.0-rc1-update1'.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Found project APP_PATH/project.json.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager] Using '/Users/nsamteladze/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1' for design time host.
>
> [ERROR:OmniSharp.Startup] The project system 'DnxProjectSystem' threw an exception.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: File name has not been set
>     at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo, System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:Start ()
>     at OmniSharp.Dnx.DesignTimeHostManager.Start (System.String hostId, System.Action`1 onConnected) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem.Initalize (IConfiguration configuration) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at OmniSharp.Startup.Configure (IApplicationBuilder app, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ILibraryManager manager, IOmnisharpEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, ISharedTextWriter writer, IOptions'1 optionsAccessor) [0x00000] in :0
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] No solution files found in APP_PATH
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.ScriptCs.ScriptCsProjectSystem] Detecting CSX files in APP_PATH.
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.ScriptCs.ScriptCsProjectSystem] Could not find any CSX files
>
> [INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Solution has finished loading