# IntelliSense suggestions not working properly in Visual Studio Code on Mac with C#

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Hello I'm using VSCode on mac and the IntelliSense suggestions don't seem to be working properly . There are some suggestions (on the image you can see there are some rectangles instead of symbols which are supposed to be there I think), but for functions for example they don't show at all when I open parentheses. I'm a complete noob with VSCode, so I'm not sure which information is relevant here. I have C# extensions installed.

[image: This is how suggestions look]

Thanks in advance.

I'm not sure what to try so I haven't tried to change any settings yet or anything like that.

Comment: The screen shot (the C# Dev Kit icon in status bar wasn't in right status) seems to indicate that you didn't log into C# Dev Kit with a valid Visual Studio subscription. Can you verify that part first?

Comment: This user seems to have the same issue, and it seems to be related to DNVM, but apparently it is outdated (it was posted 8 years ago)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467249/intellisense-doesnt-work-in-visual-studio-code-on-mac

Comment: @LexLi oh, yes, thank you, you were right, but I logged in and reopened VSCode and the issue remained

Comment: Then you might have hit a known issue or a new one, and GitHub is the right place to engage the resources, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues?q=is%3Aissue+unity+label%3Aarea-unity